# Load Desktop version of web sites

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

How can I load desktop versions of web sites(such as google, facebook) rather than mobile versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Disregard all this. Yaniv's right. Just load an `NSMutableURLRequest` to the `UIWebView` instance using the `- loadRequest:` message and set the `"User-Agent"` header to whatever you want.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:someUrl];
[rq setValue:@"Some desktop user-agent" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[webView loadRequest:rq];
```

For your information, a good choice for a desktop user-agent string is that of Chrome - it's also WebKit-based, as Safari, so WebKit-specific extensions will work. So try setting the user-agent string to

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.6 Safari/537.11

---

Original post:

You can try spoofing the user agent of UIWebView but I can't guarantee that such a fat hack will let you through the thin gate of AppStore...

```
void *object_getIvarPtr(id obj, const char *name)
{
    Ivar iv = object_getInstanceVariable(obj, name, NULL);
    off_t offset = ivar_getOffset(iv);
    return (char *)obj + offset;
}

// In some initialization routine, after having created the web view
id webViewInternal = *(id *)object_getIvarPtr(someWebView, "_internal");
id webBrowserView = *(id *)object_getIvarPtr(webViewInternal, "browserView");
id webKitWebView = [webBrowserView webView];

NSString *desktopUAStr = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.6 Safari/537.11"
[webKitWebView setCustomUserAgent:desktopUAStr];
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. works very well.. just having a warning.. it says`instance method -setCustomUserAgent not found (return type default to 'id')`

Comment: @TimTuffley yeah. Ignore that noise. And please lemme have an upvote/accept if I helped.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you going through all this hassle?  This is the wrong/LONG approach.

Just create an `NSMutableRequest` and set the `useragent` inside it and not in the `UIWebView`. Then just load the request with a `UIWebView` normal/non-private `loadRequest:`-function.