# iOS: openURL() in Desktop Mode programmatically

Tags: ios, safari

on an iPhone, a user can force Safari in desktop mode.

For example: 
long press the reload symbol -> tap on "Request Desktop Site".

Is it possible to do this programmatically? When I open Safari on an iPhone using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

is there a way to tell Safari to open the url as a Desktop Site without user interaction?

Comment: You need to use `NSMutableURLRequest` and set `User-Agent`, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766112/load-desktop-version-of-web-sites

Comment: This answer uses UIWebView. Because of some restrictions of UIWebView I'd strongly prefer to open Safari itself or at least SFSafariViewController.